# Python - automatically updating an excel based on user’s input on an online webform

Tags: python, webforms

Hi im relatively to python and I would like to build a script that would automatically import a user’s input on an online webform into a designated google/ excel sheet and frankly i dont know where to even start.

if this has been done before, could you kindly point me to it?

Thank you in advance! I hope you wouldn’t be disgusted at my questions given my lack of experience in this field.

Comment: keep google searching, and be more specific - so you won't get downvoted a looooot

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.